# How to make show/hide a non-child <div> when mouseenter/leave on a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

i've code a menu with a submenu, to show when the user hover on the main menu link.

my question is about adding and removing a class to show and hide a sub-menu container with JS and CSS3 animation, when the use mouse-enter and out on a link in the main-menu container: i've used the `data-section` attribute to match the submenu with the hovered link.

The answer seems to be pretty simple and straightforward, but i can't work it out, **because the secondary menu  is placed in another 'strip' container**, and i **would not modify the structure HTML markup**.

Here is the working code to test:

[LINK of LIVE CODE to TEST](http://jsbin.com/wisozo/2/)

Comment: Which link(s) should have a sub-element? In your demo 'working link' and 'should working link' have one.

Comment: both of them, i call it in that manner just to example.

Comment: You mean all the links should have a sub-menu element?

Comment: yes, at least they could have: if a link has a sub-menu it should show it on hover, and hide on mouseleave. now, with my code, i can't handle.

Comment: Move up from the bottom onto one. It seems to be working. I think you might get trapped moving horizontally across because of your hide timeout though.

Comment: Also, consider setting the sub-menu item to have a class-name that equals the data attribute you are setting so you can call $('.'+target) instead of accessing the sub-menu with '[data-section]' selector.

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you want to do.

Comment: Mmhhh, sorry for my bad english: simply, i would like to show the submenu when hovering the corresponding main menu link. the problem is the mouseenter / mouseout timer. it would be more simple to put the submenu INSIDE the anchor element, but i would like to have the primary menu and the submenu in different div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you switch between the two menus, you need to clear out existing ones first. Additionally, you need to clear the timers for them. In the following code, there are two functions being used: first to clear the timeout, and second to clear the visible sub-menu.

```
var $submenu = $('.' + selector);
var visSub = $('.strip-header-submenu .submenu.is-visible').not($submenu);
    if (visSub.length > 0) {
        clearHideTimeout(visSub);
        hideSubmenu(visSub);
    }
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/66xvLrL4/2/

Comment: Seems to be the perfect solution for me! I didnt'know this trick. Tomorrow i will test the code and i will mark yours as the solution for my question.